# Close activity after x minutes of inactive

Tags: java, android

I have an activity. What I want is if the user is inactive, after a time (represented by x), this activity will automatically finish. All help is appreciated.

My sample code:

```
package com.zilant.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class HelpActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_help, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. Your question is *extremely* broad/vague. We don't know what kind of help you need because you haven't told us what the problem is. Show your code and be specific about what the issue is.

Comment: This code comes with a brand new project, generated by the IDE, including those comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code of Activity that will automatically close itself after five seconds.

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private static final int DELAY = 5000;

public boolean inactive;

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {            
        if(inactive) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, DELAY);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_annotation_test);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, DELAY);

}
}
```

Now all you need to do is to change inactive variable to true after user interaction. Which will cancel activity finish and start new countdown.